# dataTable row button click

Tags: jquery, datatable

I create a dataTable in which I have two column containing < button value="http://.....">.
When I click the button, it opens a "jquery dialog". everything works. The problem is that when my dataTable contains several lines (more than five), when I click on the button NEXT for the dataTable to see the following lines, the following lines BUTTON do not respond to my click. Only the front lines button displayed answer my click. What to do?

Here is my dataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {gridGroup = $('#gridUser').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bRetrieve" : true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "bUrl": "",                         
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "<p>Recherche globale:<p> ",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Debut",
        "sPrevious": "Prec",
        "sNext":     "Suiv",
        "sLast":     "Fin"
    }
    },
    "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
    'oTableTools': {
    "sSwfPath": "https://www.gmerp.local/app/project/common/public/js/tabletools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    'aButtons': [
        {
            "sExtends": "copy",
            "sButtonText": "Copier",
            "bShowAll": true,
        },
        {
            "sExtends": "print",
            "sButtonText": "Imprimer",
            "bShowAll": true,
        },
        {   
           'sExtends':    'collection',
       'sButtonText': 'Exporter',
       'aButtons':    [ 'csv', 'xls', 'pdf' ]
        }
    ]
   },
   "bStateSave": false
});

$('#gridUser tbody td button').click(function (){
    //todo
});

});
```

and the HTML part:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="gridUser">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>EMAIL</th><th> </th><th> </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left"><td>7</td><td>root</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/7">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/7">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>26</td><td>wwwaa</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/26">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/26">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>27</td><td>wwww</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/27">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/27">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>30</td><td>soja</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/30">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/30">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>31</td><td>ss</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/31">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/31">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>32</td><td>sss</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/32">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/32">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>33</td><td>ssss</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/33">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/33">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>34</td><td>sssss</td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/edituser/34">Modifier</button></td><td><button value="https://localhost/user/session/deleteuser/34">Supprimer</button></td></tr>
</tbody>            
<tfoot>
    <tr>                        
      <th>ID</th><th>EMAIL</th><th> </th><th> </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>            
</table>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646505/when-i-click-the-next-page-in-datatables-my-jquery-selectors-arent-working-anym) Check out the solution to the older question.

Comment: @srvikram13 in duplicated link, answer uses .live() which has been removed from newer jquery versions

Comment: Sorry! I didn't bother to check the jQuery version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should delegate event:

```
$('#gridUser tbody').on('click', 'td button', function (){
    //todo
});
```

Comment: this is the best solution

Comment: A very elegant solution. With this, you also do not have to use the "initComplete" callback from dataTables plugin. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me with a newer version of DataTable (1.10.9). I was previously using a row click event but changed it to the button as I didn't want row clicks to unintentionally trigger the event handler function

```
    $table = $('table#summary').DataTable();

    $table.on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = $table.row(this).data();
        var taskID = data[0];
    });
```

Button click example

```
    $table = $('table#summary').DataTable();

    $table.on('click', 'button.edit-task', function () {
        var closestRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $table.row(closestRow).data();
        var taskID = data[0];
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This one

```
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="Mybtn">Click me</button></td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var Dtable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dtable = $("#MyTable").DataTable();
    });


    $('#MyTable').on('click', '.Mybtn', function () {

        var RowIndex = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = Dtable.row(RowIndex).data();
        alert(data[1]);
    });
</script>
```