# jQuery on click event not working with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery datatables plugin. Each row has two action buttons to confirm or cancel the item in the table.

I am getting problem to add on click event for both of them. Buttons added directly into the json data.

```
(function ($){
    $(function (){

        let confirm_button = $('.gs-confirm-order');
        let cancel_button = $('.gs-cancel-order');
    
    
        // cancel order process
        cancel_button.on('click', function (){
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel this order? Undo is not possible.')) {
            console.log('Item cancelled.');
            } else {
            console.log('Operation cancelled.');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

within the document ready also not working

```
(function ($){
    $(document).ready(function (){
        let response_alert = $('#response');
        response_alert.hide();

        let confirm_button = $('.gs-confirm-order');
        let cancel_button = $('.gs-cancel-order');

        // cancel order process
        cancel_button.on('click', function (){
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel this order? Undo is not possible.')) {
                console.log('Item cancelled.');
            } else {
                console.log('Operation cancelled.');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi , change your selector like this `$(document).on('click','.gs-cancel-order',function(){ // your code})` and see if that works.

Comment: I have tried that too but it is then considering entire document. Even clicking on the page also triggers the event.

Comment: or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117485/datatable-row-button-click) ?

Comment: Let me try that way.

Comment: @Swati there is an issue. If I use variable the even trigger by clicking anywhere on the document but if I pass class itself `.gs-cancel-order` it works. I can pass the class, but the problem is, I have to refer the same object after AJAX complete. Updating class etc.

Comment: Please show ajax code as well which is calling that click event ..etc.

Comment: I am still writing ajax code.

Comment: Did you write that ? without seeing further code its difficult to suggest.

Comment: @Swati yes it is working. Thanks